# python threading: max number of threads to run

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

let's say i have something similar to:

```
def worker(name):
    time.sleep(10)
    print name
    return

thrs = []
for i in range(1000):
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(i,))
    thrs.append(t1)

for t in thrs:
    t.start()
```

Is there way to specify how many threads can run in parallel? in the above case, all 1000 will run in parallel

Comment: Is it  `threads.append(t1)`, I think  `thrs.append(t1)` right ?

Comment: I don't understand the question ... you have specified how many threads you want: 1000, if you want another number, can't you change this?

Comment: @maxymoo They're not sure how many are possible

Comment: Need manage CPU and RAM processes. And `for t in thrs:    t.start()` not parallel function.

Comment: i have 1000 things that needs to be run. but i want them to run at like 10 at a time or what not. i suppose i can just run then join and run then join until no more is left but i was trying to see if there is something that already does that

Comment: @dsgdfg isnt it asynchrous so if inside worker func, it has io bound logic, it would be paralleized, right?

Comment: Use a logic can't resolve synchronism , maybe define a `CPU clock based trigger` for solution. Python timing very fuzzy on logical conditions. @ealeon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done using [`multiprocessing.dummy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.dummy) which provides a threaded version of the [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) api.

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool

pool = Pool(10)
result = pool.map(worker, range(1000))
```

In python 3, [`concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor) usually provides a nicer interface.